# having trouble understanding this code

Tags: python, recursion, nested, depth

I just started learning recursion and I have an assignment to write a program that tells the nesting depth of a list.  Well,  I browsed around and found working code to do this,  but I'm still having trouble understanding how it works. Here's the code:

```
def depth(L) :
    nesting = [] 
    for c in L:
        if type(c)  == type(nesting) :
            nesting.append(depth(c)) 
    if len(nesting)  > 0:
        return 1 + max(nesting)
    return 1
```

So naturally,  I start to get confused at the line with the append that calls recursion. Does anyone have a simple way of explaining what's going on here? I'm not sure what is actually being appended, and going through it with test cases in my head isn't helping.  Thanks!

edit: sorry if the formatting is poor,  I typed this from my phone

Comment: It would be better to use `type(L)` instead of `type(nesting)`. Then the function could also deal with, for example, nested tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me show it to you the easy way, change the code like this:
(### are the new lines I added to your code so you can watch what is happening there)

```
def depth(L) :
    nesting = []
    for c in L:
        if type(c)  == type(nesting) :
            print 'nesting before append', nesting ###      
            nesting.append(depth(c))
            print 'nesting after append', nesting ###
    if len(nesting)  > 0:
        return 1 + max(nesting)
    return 1
```

Now lets make a list with the depth of three:

```
l=[[1,2,3],[1,2,[4]],'asdfg']
```

You can see our list has 3 element. one of them is a list, the other is a list which has another list in itself and the last one is a string. You can clearly see the depth of this list is 3 (i.e there are 2 lists nested together in the second element of the main list)

Lets run this code:

```
>>> depth(l)
nesting before append []
nesting after append [1]
nesting before append [1]
nesting before append []
nesting after append [1]
nesting after append [1, 2]
3
```

Piece of cake! this function appends 1 to the nesting. then if the element has also another list it appends 1 + maximum number in nesting which is the number of time function has been called itself. and if the element is a string, it skips it.

At the end, it returns the maximum number in the nesting which is the maximum number of times recursion happened, which is the number of time there is a list inside list in the main list, aka depth. In our case recursion happened twice for the second element + 1=3 as we expected.

If you still have problem getting it, try to add more `print` statements or other variables to the function and watch them carefully and eventually you'll get it.

Comment: Thanks, the print statements did help me to understand it a bit better

Answer (score 1):

So what this seems to be is a function that takes a list and calculates, as you put it, the nesting depth of it. nesting is a list, so what `if type(c) == type(nesting)` is saying is: if the item in list `L` is a list, run the function again and append it and when it runs the function again, it will do the same test until there are no more nested lists in list `L` and then return 1 + the max amount of nested lists because every list has a depth of 1.

Please tell me if any of this is unclear

Comment: In Python they are called lists not arrays.

Comment: sorry, I use numpy a lot so I am in the habit of calling them arrays. I edited it

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a couple of examples.

First, let's consider a list with only one level of depth. For Example, `[1, 2, 3]`.

In the above list, the code starts with a call to `depth()` with `L = [1, 2, 3]`. It makes an empty list `nesting`. Iterates over all the elements of `L` i.e `1, 2, 3` and does not find a single element which passes the test `type(c)  == type(nesting)`. The check that `len(nesting) > 0` fails and the code returns a 1, which is the depth of the list.

Next, let's take an example with a depth of 2, i.e `[[1, 2], 3]`. The function `depth()` is called with `L = [[1, 2], 3]` and an empty list `nesting` is created. The loop iterates over the 2 elements of L i.e `[1, 2] , 3` and since `type([1, 2]) == type(nesting)`, `nesting.append(depth(c))` is called. Similar to the previous example, `depth(c)` i.e `depth([1, 2])` returns a 1 and `nesting` now becomes `[1]`. After the execution of the loop, the code evaluates the test `len(nesting) > 0` which results in `True` and `1 + max(nesting)` which is `1 + 1 = 2` is returned.

Similarly, the code follows for the depth 3 and so on.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks, this was a helpful answer too

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm visits the nested lists and adds one for each level of recursion. The call chain is like this:

```
depth([1, 2, [3, [4, 5], 6], 7]) =
    1 + depth([3, [4, 5], 6]) = 3
        1 + depth([4, 5]) = 2
            1
```

Since depth([4,5]) never enters the `if type(c) == type(nesting)` condition because no element is a list, it returns 1 from the outer return, which is the base case.

In the case where, for a given depth, you have more than one nested list, e.g. `[1, [2, 3], [4, [5, 6]]`, both the max depth of `[2,3]`and `[4, [5, 6]]` are appended on a depth call, of which the max is returned by the inside return.