# Find the depth of nested braces

Tags: python

What I want to do is find the depth of nested braces. For example, the depth of [] would be 1, [[]] would be 2, and so on and so forth.

Here is my code so far, but it is wrong.  I want to learn more about this concept so that if I see it again, I understand it.

```
def measure_the_depth(lst):
    lst = ['[]']
    return lst.count('[]')
```

Comment: Why are you assigning to the function parameter? That will replace the value that was supplied by the caller.

Comment: Are you trying to find the depth of nested lists, or the number of nested braces in a string?

Comment: If you want max depth of lists, you should use a recursive function. If you want max depth of a string containing brackets, you should iterate over the characters, counting successive `[`.

Comment: Your code so far makes no sense, you didn't really think about the problem at all. Counting a single string doesn't calculate depth.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198018/having-trouble-understanding-this-code/16198625#16198625

Comment: Your argument is name `lst` which suggests a list. Is your argument a list or a string?

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse the string while keeping count of the number of open brackets. The maximum number of open brackets you encounter will correspond to the depth.

```
def measure_the_depth(lst):
    max_count = 0
    count = 0
    for char in lst:
        # count brackets
        if char == '[':
            count += 1
        elif char == ']':
            count -= 1
        # update max count
        if count > max_count:
            max_count = count
    return max_count
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer That's not what this function returns.

Comment: `measure_the_depth("[[[]]]") -> 3` as long as a string is passed it should give the correct answer

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize they where passing a string (I was influenced by the argument name), `measure_the_depth([[[]]]) ` does return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your nested braces are going to be always valid , i will write only the core logic

count only the [ in the string

```
def countDepth(lst):
       maxCount=0
       currentcount=0
       for l in lst:
           if l=='[':
                currentCount+=1
                if currentCount>maxCount:
                    maxCount=currentCount
           else:
                currentCount-=1
       return
```

something of this sort will do.
Here i am just trying to keep the track of opening and closing braces...and then returning maxCount